# Should I drop duplicates over features but no target

Tags: dataset, data, data-cleaning, training

I'm in a debate with someone about a problem where there are duplicates over features (i.e. $ X_1 = X_2 $ but $ Y_1 != Y_2 $).

My point of view is that we should keep those datas, as they can be representative, and so be interesting for train and test datas. My debater thinks that it can bias the results.

I tried to find papers/articles about that, but didn't found any. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

On the one side, you should remove them if you do not know how the target variables (i.e., labels) have been collected. It is immediately observed that any supervised learning algorithm would be confused when trying to separate such cases (e.g., think about entropy-based learning), assuming that they (all) belong to the training set.

On the other side, you should keep one of them if you have enough knowledge about the targets and have few data points in your training set.

In any case, duplicates must be adequately addressed. For example, they should belong to either the training or test set, but not both; this will avoid confusing the resulting model (after the training phase). In my experience, there are papers addressing the duplication issue and open-source implementations for it (e.g., [dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe) in Python).